# showing the estimator of $\sigma^2$

Tags: self-study, anova, variance, manova, unbiased-estimator

Let's take a one way ANOVA Model as $Y_{ij}=\mu + \tau_i +\epsilon_{ij}$    $i=1,2,3$  and $j=1,...,n_i$ and $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0,\sigma^2),   \ \ \ \forall (i,j).$

Sample variance for factor level is 
$$S_i^2=\frac{1}{n_i-1} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} y_{ij}^2- \frac{(\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}y_{ij})^2}{n_i}\right)$$ $i=1,2,3$

How can one show that the estimator of $\sigma^2$ is equal to the following?

$$S^2 =\frac{(n_1 -1)S_1^2 +(n_2-1)S_2^2 +(n_3-1)S_3^2}{n_1+n_2+n_3-3}$$

Comment: This looks like a self-study question. If so, we expect an attempt at solution. It's not CV policy to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm studying an exam. And so, i'm asknig this question here. Not homework! I cannot think any idea about the question, thus sorry for this:(. Please teach me how to solve this question. Thank you for helping:) dear @NickCox

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions for policy.

Comment: the phrasing "the estimator" implies there's only one ... which isn't the case. There's all manner of estimators of $\sigma^2$. It's *an* estimator, and a pretty good one but you need to add an adjective that narrows the scope of the possible answers if you want that to be "the estimator"

Comment: @NickCox, I never add the `[ss]` tag for the OP. I ask them to add it themselves & read its wiki (w/ a link). That way there is a higher probability they will be familiar w/ our policies. If they do add the tag, it is some indication they now understand them (especially if they state what they've done so far). OTOH, if they don't add the tag after a period of time, it suggests closure is appropriate. Those signals are lost when we add the tag for them. FWIW, text I like to use can be found [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2486/7290).

Comment: My general feeling about non-homework self study questions that pertain to standard results (as this one is) is that we should be more accepting, and perhaps more liberal than usual about providing a full solution rather than just a hint. This is the sort of statement we often see unproven in an introductory textbook  (or lecture slides) with a footnote saying "for proof, consult any standard text on linear models" or worse still "interested readers may prove this as an exercise"; asking how to do it seems quite reasonable and of interest to later readers.

Comment: @gung Thanks for expanding on your practice. I cross-referenced to a fuller statement. Personally, I regard fine distinctions between different kinds of self-study as really hard to make consistently: we can't expect detailed explanations from posters of their particular circumstances. But I am happy to regard being generous as a higher virtue than being strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the two population case because it is easier to write, recall that

$$ w = \text{average} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} x_i + \sum^m_{i=1} y_i}{n+m} = \frac{n\bar{x} + m \bar{y}}{n+m} $$

for two populations $X_i ... X_{N_1}$ with observations $x_i ... x_n$ and $Y_i ... Y_{N_2}$ with observations $y_i ... y_m$.

For total variance, we can write

$$ \begin{aligned} (n + m -1) V &= \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - w)^2 +  \sum^m_{i=1} (y_i - w)^2 \\ &= \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x} + \bar{x} - w)^2 +  \sum^m_{i=1} (y_i - \bar{y} + \bar{y} - w)^2 \end{aligned} $$

Knowing that

$$ \begin{aligned} \bar{x}-w &= \frac{m(\bar{x} - \bar{y})}{n + m} \\ \bar{y}-w &= \frac{m(\bar{y} - \bar{x})}{n + m} \\ \sum^n_{i=1} (x_i - \bar{x}) &= 0 \\ \sum^m_{i=1} (y_i - \bar{y}) &= 0 \end{aligned} $$

How can you expand the above to redefine the variance? How can you extend this to three populations?

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be a full answer but a series of hints.

Indeed the sample variance is given by the formula you have written. One crucial assumption of ANOVA though is that the error term is homoscedastic, meaning that it follows the same variance for all populations. What this means is that you can combine all the information about the variability across samples into one estimator. This is reminiscent of the situation of the pooled variance in a t-test, again under the assumption of equal population variances.

The question of course is, why do you need to combine sample variances like that instead of taking simple averages? Try to see what happens when you take expectations to find out.

I hope this clears it up a bit.